# Assign toValue from an int

Tags: xcode, integer, cabasicanimation

I'm doing an animation and want the toValue to get bigger every time i tap an image. My code will work (but doesn't now, of course), but how do you make a toValue an integer?

I have this:

```
int comboTapAnim = (comboTap / 10) + 1;
```

then in the animation:

```
theAnimation.toValue = [comboTapAnim];
```

Xcode no likey. I have tried other combinations but it must be an NSNumber but I want it to be an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer!!

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:<#(int)#>]
```